# Over which commutative rings do we have Smith normal form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

It is well-known that matrices over a PID
always have Smith normal form as in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form. What about general rings which may not even be noetherian?

Comment: see here also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31275/does-smith-normal-form-imply-pid

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm requires at least a Bézout domain to express GCDs as linear combinations, and I think it requires some sort of bound on factorizations to prevent chasing some infinite factorizations forever.

The safest thing to do to control factorizations would be to assume it is a UFD, but a Bézout UFD is already a PID.